# Nusach of the Satmar Siddur

Tags: prayer-book, chasidut-hasidism, satmar

Many chassidussim use their own nuschaot, typically based on Nusach haAri or the so-called [Nusach Sefard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Sefard). For example, Sudilkover Chassidim use their own variant, as discussed in [this blog post](http://asimplejew.blogspot.com/2007/07/nusach-sudilkov-changes-from-standard.html).

What is are some of the variants in tefillah used in Satmar (relative to a "standard" Nusach Sefard, if it exists)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I removed the passages which made this a(n accidental) duplicate. The dupe is about which siddur they use, this is about what's in the siddur.

Comment: http://www.koltorahonline.com/index.php/artists/gluck-r-duvid/nusach-hatfilah-satmar.html

Comment: Here is the answer: "Historic Prayer Book Used by Satmar Rebbe Joel Teitelbaum OB"M"
http://www.ebay.com/itm/222625469643?ul_noapp=true

Answer (score 3):

The Satmar Rebbe, R' Yoel Teitelbaum himself, would only daven from the Berditchever Siddur, *[Siddur Tefillah Yesharah v'Keter Nehora](http://www.nehora.com/siddur-tefila-yeshara-vketer-nehora-2-vol/)*.

[[Source](http://breslovcenter.blogspot.com/2016/10/origins-of-berditchever-siddur-tefilah.html)]

Comment: I actually meant to ask the family I stayed by over Shabbos, as they're Satmar-affiliated

Comment: Also, do you know what (if any) differences there are between TYK"N and Siddur Yetev Lev?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - I could not tell you for sure as I do not daven from these siddurim (I am not a Satmar) but I'm fairly sure they are identical, at least for a lot of it.

Comment: Yes in the Hakdama of Tefila Yeshare, the Berdi

Comment: How do you know this? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.